# C# - Cannot populate grandchild of second child in tree view

Tags: c#

I am populating a treeview from an arrayList and I am not able to populate the grandchildren of the second child.

I was going for something like this

```
parent
 - child1
    - gc1
    - gc2
 - child2
    - gc1
    - gc2
```

But I am stuck with only just populating the child2 as I am having exceptions (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) when trying to populate the grandchildren of the second child

```
        string currentDatabaseParent = "";
        string currentSchemaParent = "";
        string currentTableParent = "";
        int databasecount = 0;
        int schemacount = 0;
        int tablecount = 0;

        foreach (var schema in schemaArr)
        {
            int order = Array.IndexOf(schemaArr, schema);
            if ((schema.column_name != "Number") && (schema.schema_name != "INFORMATION_SCHEMA") && (schema.database_name != "SAMPLE_DATA"))
            {
                if ((currentDatabaseParent == "") || (currentDatabaseParent != schema.database_name))
                {
                    treeViewSchemaList.Nodes.Add(schema.database_name);
                    sb.AppendLine(schema.database_name);
                    currentDatabaseParent = schema.database_name;
                }
                else if (currentDatabaseParent != schema.database_name)
                {
                    treeViewSchemaList.Nodes.Add(schema.database_name);
                    sb.AppendLine(schema.database_name);
                    currentDatabaseParent = schema.database_name;
                    databasecount = databasecount + 1;
                    schemacount = 0;
                    tablecount = 0;
                }



                if ((currentSchemaParent == ""))
                {
                    treeViewSchemaList.Nodes[schemacount].Nodes.Add(schema.schema_name);
                    sb.AppendLine("     - " + schema.schema_name);
                    currentSchemaParent = schema.schema_name;
              
                }
                else if (currentSchemaParent != schema.schema_name)
                {

                    treeViewSchemaList.Nodes[schemacount].Nodes.Add(schema.schema_name);
                    sb.AppendLine("     - " + schema.schema_name);
                    currentSchemaParent = schema.schema_name;
                    schemacount = schemacount + 1;
                    
                }

                if (currentTableParent == "")
                {
                    treeViewSchemaList.Nodes[schemacount].Nodes[tablecount].Nodes.Add(schema.table_name);
                    sb.AppendLine("          - " + schema.table_name);
                    currentTableParent = schema.table_name;

                }
                else if (currentTableParent != schema.table_name)
                { 
                    treeViewSchemaList.Nodes[schemacount].Nodes[tablecount].Nodes.Add(schema.table_name);
                    sb.AppendLine("          - " + schema.table_name);
                    currentTableParent = schema.table_name;
                    tablecount = tablecount + 1;
                }


                //DataType dataType = new DataType();
                //dataType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataType>(schema.data_type);
                //sb.AppendLine("               - " + schema.column_name + "(" + dataType.Type + ")");
                //treeViewSchemaList.Nodes[databasecount].Nodes[schemacount].Nodes[tablecount].Nodes.Add(schema.column_name + "(" + schema.data_type + ")");

            }
        }
```

The code stucks to this when viewed from the StringBuilder

```
parent
 - child1
    - gc1
    - gc2
 - child2
```

I have already tried modifying some code by manipulating the count variables but still can't get to work

Comment: Don't just modify it. Debug the code. Then you know where you get the Exception and from there you can ask yourself why.

Comment: it is given that i'm debugging it at the same time.